# Failed to read spring beans xml with spring schema document in weblogic12 during deployment

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, weblogic12c

While deploying the application beans.xml file is not able to validating the schema with xsd we are getting the errors while starting the server.

Below is the error log:

```
<May 30, 2019 8:21:20 PM IST> <Warning> org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap <cozw7dev21007> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1559227880134> <BEA-000000> <WELD-001208 Warning when validating file:/X:/base-domain-12/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/gbrs-ws/pk9aag/war/WEB-INF/beans.xml@26 against xsd. schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.>
```

Below is the spring beans configuration file definition.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" xmlns:http-conf="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd" 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

     http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
     http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
     http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd">
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've received the same error trying to use the xsd via Intellij.
I had tried to defined the xsd in the Intellij settings: 'Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Schemas and DTDs' External Schemas and DTDs.
I had defined it there but at the incorrect location.